# Invalidate cache from two channel expiry dates

Tags: templating, cache, expiration

I have two channels: A event and a news channel which I want the cache to expire based on both their expiry Date.

```
{% set newsDate = craft.entries.section('newsDate').order('expiryDate asc').first() %}
{% set eventDate = craft.entries.section('event').order('konzertStartdate asc').first() %}
{% set currentTime = now |date('c') %}

{% if currentTime <= newsDate %}
    {% set invalidate = newsDate.expiryDate | date('c') %}
{% else %}
    {% set invalidate = auffuehrung.konzertStartdate |date('c') %}
{% endif %}

{% cache unless invalidate %}
 {# blablabla #}
{% endcache %}
```

As you can see I create two variables and then check which one is newer. But its not working properly.

The news never seem to invalidate the cache.

Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it possible that you wanted to write "until" instead of "unless" in the template code?

Comment: If you output `{{ newsDate }}`, `{{ eventDate }}` and `{{ currentTime }}`, are they what you expect?  Maybe a timezone difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error was with the `date` format in the date comparison conditional and the `until` tag instead of `unless`

```
{% if currentTime <= newsDate | date('c') %} {# those two dates were formated differentely #}
    {% set invalidate = newsDate.expiryDate | date('c') %}
{% else %}
    {% set invalidate = auffuehrung.konzertStartdate |date('c') %}
{% endif %}

{% cache until invalidate %} {# not unless #}
 {# blablabla #}
{% endcache %}
```